# Regex to exclude 8 digit number

Tags: regex

I have the following URL schema:

```
/test/how-are-you.html
/test/hello-how-are-you.html
/test/im-fine.html
/test/im-fine/how-are-you/
/test/im-fine/hello-how-are-you/
/test/happy-1-day.html
/test/thanks-123.html
/test/thanks-1234.html
/test/thanks-12345.html
/test/hoe-are-you-10012396.html (always 8 numbers)
/test/im-fine-10012396.html (always 8 numbers)
/test/hello-52345786.html (always 8 numbers)
```

Can you give me a regex to exclude the last 3 examples, while including the rest?
I tried something like

```
^\/test\/?[\w\-]*\/?[\w\-]*([^0-9]{8})\/?
```

and failed ;)

Best, Daniel

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew edit the question.

Comment: So, what is wrong with the pattern?

Comment: Thats a good question, it's not working, that's all I know. I need the [^0-9] for 8 digits.

Comment: Try `^\/test\/(?!.*\d{8}\.html$).*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVPjYq/1).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^\/test\/(?!.*\d{8}\.html$).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVPjYq/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/test\/`  - `/test/` string
- `(?!.*\d{8}\.html$)` - if there is any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, then 8 digits and `.html` at the end of string, fail the match
- `.*$` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I'm not so familiar with negative lookahead :) Is there any other option without negative lookahead?

Comment: @hasche90 Yes, but if your tool supports the lookahead, it is much shorter/cleaner.